# Running python script from shell in Emacs results in delayed output

Tags: python, microsoft-windows, shell

I'm trying to run a python script from a Windows shell (invoked via `M-x shell` or `M-x powershell`) inside Emacs.

However, no output is shown via `print` statements until I after I hit a `raw_input` statement AND provide input. In other words, the script shows no almost no output in the window until after I provide input, at which point all the output that should have been printed before get shown.

I say "almost" because `LOGGER.info` statements still get shown in my Emacs shell window, where `LOGGER=logger.getLogger("loggerName")`

For example if my script were...

```
LOGGER.info("Starting script")
print "Hello world."
raw_input("What's your name?").strip()
```

I would see

```
Starting script
```

And then nothing until I typed in something, at which point I would see:

```
Hello world.
What's your name?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps buffering is at play and the logger implementation flushes the buffer.  Try running with unbuffered stdin, stdout, stderr:

- `python -u yourscript.py`
- `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 yourscript.py in your environment`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Could I perhaps trouble you for an explanation of why that  worked?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I would say that buffering is a way to optimize overall throughput at the cost of latency.  For example, instead of issuing separate system calls for each character, you buffer them up into a larger chunks.  Then a question is when to flush the buffer: size? time? special characters (eg newlines)?  never and require the user/developer to explicitly flush the buffer?  In your case, the `print()` isn't doing any explicit flushing but in newer pythons, there is a `flush` option you can use if you don't want to use something as blunt as `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`.